# Couchbase 6.0 + springboot (InvalidPasswordException)

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Hi i am newbie to Couchbase and created a Springboot application with Couchbase 6.0.

When i installed Couchbase, it asked me to create username and password and i set username="admin" and password="password" and then i created "student" bucket.

I have done all the requisite config in application.properties file.

```
spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts=127.0.0.1
spring.couchbase.bucket.name=student
spring.couchbase.bucket.password=password
```

On server start, i am getting following error

```
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: null
```

Couchbase web console, there is a **Security** tab,
I added, username "admin" (which i created during Couchbase server installation) over there and given **full admin** access
[image]

**On server restart again, I have faced same issue**

then i added one more user "student" (same as my bucket name) over there and given **full admin** access

[image]

**this time my server started successfully and i did not get any exception**

So i have two questions here,

1: Do i need to create as many as username as i have buckets in my 
    Couchbase server in security tab ?.

2: Let say i want to use username "admin" only (which i created during Couchbase server installation), how would i achieve this ?.

Can someone throw some light on this behaviour ?

Comment: Are you using Community or Enterprise?

Comment: @MatthewGroves, I am using Enterprise version .

Comment: I have encountered the same problem with Spring boot 2.1.2 and Couchbase 6.0

Answer (score 8):

Pre couchbase 4.5, buckets had passwords, where if you need to access a bucket you'll have to supply the bucket name and its password. After 4.5 they implemented [rbac](https://blog.couchbase.com/administrative-role-based-access-control-in-4-5/) (Role-Based Access Control) and dropped bucket-level passwords.

So for people that upgraded their couchbase but don't want to change their code or make a new release, a work-around was suggested, create a username per bucket, where the username is the bucket name and the password is the same for all users, that way `spring-data-couchbase` still authenticates successfully when ran.

Now rbac is added to `couchbase-java-client` & `spring-data-couchbase` (considering you're using latest version, not sure at which specific version they added it), so if you want to use a single username to connect to all your buckets you will need a [class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#configuration-java) that `extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration` and then

```
@Override
protected String getUsername() {
    return "admin";
}
```

And supply the password via the old `bucketPassword()` method.

I don't think you can do it through `application.properties` yet because the  `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure` dependency is still not updated to accommodate for the latest `spring-data-couchbase` changes.

Also a note, the username that you've created through the security tab have nothing to do with the user that you created through the installation wizard. The user you've created through the initial installation is a master user, can't be removed, you won't see it under the security tab and it have full admin privileges. You still can define a username with same name through the security tab (I just learned that) but then you'll have 2 accounts, same user, different pass (or maybe same pass even but I'm not even sure how it's handled by couchbase, I mean if we have 2 accounts called 'Administrator' with the same password and then a login happens on web console, which user is considered? Maybe someone can tell us.)

Comment: getUserName() is not available, i am using Couchbase 6 enterprise edition and springboot 2.0.6. and with spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: Upgrade to the stable release 2.1.0 and you'll get the method.

Answer (score 1):

I got an alternative for this by overriding couchbaseClusterInfo() method in config class.

```
    @Override
    @Bean(name = BeanNames.COUCHBASE_CLUSTER_INFO)
    public ClusterInfo couchbaseClusterInfo() throws Exception {
        return couchbaseCluster().authenticate("admin","password").clusterManager().info();
    }
```

this is working fine.